# Angular2 PrimeNG: How to match the code with the code in the value and set the model to that value object

Tags: angular, primeng

When I am trying to load initial data from service, PrimeNG dropdowns are not working. Please find below code and description.
I am using PrimeNG dropdown with the data as below.

```
  this.cities = [];
  this.cities.push({label:'Select ', value:null});
  this.cities.push({label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}});
  this.cities.push({label:'Rome', value:{id:2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'}});
  this.cities.push({label:'London', value:{id:3, name: 'London', code:'LDN'}});
  this.cities.push({label:'Istanbul', value:{id:4, name: 'Istanbul', code:'IST'}});
  this.cities.push({label:'Paris', value:{id:5, name: 'Paris', code:'PRS'}});
```

But my initial service is giving data as cities "Code"(ex:'NY') only (not the value object as mentioned above).

Please help me out how to match the code with the code in the value and set the model to that value object.
And also in which event I can achieve the above task in angular2.

Comment: Add more source code.

Comment: Please, supply at least a code snippet showing the way you bind the `dropdown` to the data. This means the interaction with *PrimeNG* code.